# How to clean some of EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

My app has some instances of `EditText`. I have to clean all the `EditText`s when I
 click the button. I need to write a condition cleaning all the `EditText`s
 in which some of `EditText`s are empty. How I will do it?

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,null);
        seekBar1 = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1SeekBar1);
        seekBar2 = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1SeekBar2);
        seekBar3=v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1SeekBar3);

        edTxt1=v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1EditText1);
        edTxt2=v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1EditText2);
        edTxt3=v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1EditText3);

        fragment1button1=v.findViewById(R.id.fragment1Button1);
        fragment1button1.setOnClickListener(this);}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt( edTxt1.getText().toString());
        int val2=Integer.parseInt( edTxt2.getText().toString());
        int val3=Integer.parseInt( edTxt3.getText().toString());

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.fragment1Button1:
                if(edTxt1.equals("")){
                    edTxt1.getText().clear();
                    edTxt2.getText().clear();
                    edTxt3.getText().clear();
                }else if(edTxt2.equals("")){
                    edTxt1.getText().clear();
                    edTxt2.getText().clear();
                    edTxt3.getText().clear();}
                else if (edTxt3.equals("")){
                    edTxt1.getText().clear();
                    edTxt2.getText().clear();
                    edTxt3.getText().clear();}
                break;}
}
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what do you want. Please make sense

Comment: from my understanding is you want a condition to clear all those edittext if there is any empty string in those edittext?

Comment: Sopheak Sok. Yes, right

Comment: @Iwantask pls try my answer. if it's still not working you can comment below I'll edit more

Comment: What to you mean by clear? Remove or change text to empty?

Comment: pb772. Of course remove

Comment: @Iwantask wait, so you want to remove the whole edittext that is empty right?

Comment: will there are 2 thing i don't understand it ( first you realy need to declare what do you need to your problem containt in 2 simple things first if(edTxt1.getText().toString().equals("")) ) , and sec is gettext().clear(); ---- idon't know what u wan't anyway try to use trim() if there are space  (((( edTxt1getText().toString().trim().equals("") ))) and you can replace this gettext().clear();  to settext("") )) if not both work for you then your button have an issue goodluck

Comment: Sopheak Sok. No, I еxplain in detail:  I have 3 edittext, For example, if I fill in the first, second, but the third edit text is left empty, then when I click on the button, I’ll need to clear only the completed text. So for all the options for filling EditTexts, need to write a condition.

Comment: Hassan Badawi. Your options have been suggested by other people. They did not help, my button is working, I have already found the right solution. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is incorrect because of checking empty editext is incorrect. Just change if condition to : if(edTxt1..getText().toString().matches(""))

Comment: Moreover, I never seen your situation before. LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set 'EditText` is empty just use

```
if(edTxt1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setText("");
    edTxt2.setText("");
    edTxt3.setText("");
} else if(edTxt2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setText("");
    edTxt2.setText("");
    edTxt3.setText("");
} else if (edTxt3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setText("");
    edTxt2.setText("");
    edTxt3.setText("");
}
break;
```

or if you want to remove edittext

```
if (edTxt1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if(edTxt2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if (edTxt3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTxt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edTxt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(edTxt1.equals(""))`

Your conditions are wrong. They should look like this:

```
if(edTxt1.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Comment: It did not help

Comment: did you do it in all 3 conditions?

Comment: Yes, I did all 3 conditions

Comment: so when you click on the button, the edit text is not getting cleared?

Comment: nupadhyaya. Yes, the edit text is not getting cleared

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set text of an edit text to null:

```
edTxt1.setText("");
```

Otherwise you can disappear it setting to invisible.

```
edTxt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  switch(view.getId())

{
    case R.id.fragment1Button1:
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edTxt1.getText().toString())) {
            edTxt1.getText().clear();
            edTxt2.getText().clear();
            edTxt3.getText().clear();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edTxt2.getText().toString())) {
            edTxt1.getText().clear();
            edTxt2.getText().clear();
            edTxt3.getText().clear();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edTxt3.getText().toString())) {
            edTxt1.getText().clear();
            edTxt2.getText().clear();
            edTxt3.getText().clear();
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: this is probably correct, but I have already found another solution

Answer (score 0):

For every `EditText` do it like this

```
if (!edTx.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    edTx.setText("");
}
```

Comment: It did not help